# Access to the model element after filtering in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I can not access the model field after applying the filter in the template, like this:

```
{{service_item_v|get_first|first|get_item:'price'.service}}
```

The problem is that it throws an error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /payment/

Could not parse the remainder: '.service' from 'service_item_v|get_first|first|get_item:'price'.service'
```

The element finds correctly if you remove the field name from the dot. Also the element has this field, since it gets it if you do not apply the filter.

The question is how to access the field in this case?

Comment: remove quotes around `'price'.service` to `price.service`

Comment: @Anjaneyulu Batta This is a custom filter and if I remove these quotes then I can not access the item.

Comment: let your custom filter return price.service

Comment: @Goran it's a good idea, but I'd like to use the template engine, because then I'll have to build such filters for many fields. And these are crutches. Сan there be any symbol denoting the end of the filter? Or a way to wrap the result of the filtering. Like skulls in the usual syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the result of filtering through "with" under another name. And after that you can access the attributes of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it on that way, it's not how it works. Because we can't see what your filter doing, I can suggest two things:

1. Create another filter or add more arguments to your filter `get_item:'price,service'`
   Then in your filter split values:

   ```
   def get_item(value):
       values_list = value.split(",")
       # do something with values from the list
   ```
2. create a function in your model instead of template filter and do filtering there.

   ```
   def get_item(self):
       price = # your logic
       return price.service
   ```

Then in your template just `{{ service_item_v.get_item }}`